# Using { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 } in ActionMailer in Production.rb for deployment to VPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, vps

This is the first time I'm working with actionmailer in production.

Earlier I deployed an App to a VPS server. I haven't assigned a domain to it yet so it is only an IP address.

I configured the action mailer settings, but I'm curious about this line:
`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }`can I use the Ip address of the server instead of `{ host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }`or does the server act as a localhost after the app is deployed with this setting?

Here is the setup code in the `production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
  user_name: ENV["SMTP_USER"],
  password: ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"],
  domain: "gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  authentication: :login,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

Once you have configured this and you use these settings to send the mail via gmail server. The default url will be used as the domain name of website/application like say for forgot password to users.

```
  http://localhost:3000/forgot_password?email="fd@ds.com"
```

You should be changing this to the domain name or the ip where the application code is hosted. localhost is used only for development setups.

Comment: Ok thank you..thats exactly what I was looking for.   So would I then put IP address like this `{ host: '123.123.123.123', port: ???? }` What about the port? can it remains the same?

Comment: why would have a port on a production setup, it should default to 80 if its being exposed to users else go ahead with port

Comment: of course, silly me :)  do I then set the host like `{ host: '123.123.123.123' }`?

Comment: yes, it will work like this http://123.123.123.123/forgot_password?email="fd@ds.com"